# How do I figure out why my html,css, bootstrap is not showing anything on the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is an example of HTML code rendered out from asp.net web form in which a previous person used tons of panels and tabs ... as I have been gutting many pages with Bootstrap, this particular page is not showing anything other than the top menu.

I tried putting in snippets of code,  commenting out some tags.  I saved it as a fiddle and hoping someone knows how to troubleshoot why all the code, but most of it just does not display.  Bootstrap 3.x , and asp.net webforms 4.5 (not that it matters )

Thoughts?

Tags like this causing issues?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tazmanrising/TTPGm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `visibility: hidden;` inline css styles.

Comment: Good eye !  that is it.

Answer (score 0):

it's there, it is just behind the header. bootstrap by default has a class that is floated like that in the navbar. Try removing the nav classes and you'll see it show up. Also, you can use your browser inspector tools to see it in the source code, to verify that it rendered.